# CSS3 transform transition stutters when value changes frequently (not performance related)

Tags: css, animation, transform, css-transitions, transition

I'm currently building a compass app in HTML and CSS in a PhoneGap project with the [DeviceOrientation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation) to get the compass heading.

I created [a jsbin to emulate the heading change](http://jsbin.com/weruzujizi/21/edit).

The problem I'm having is that when the value changes frequently (every 200 ms), the CSS transition stutters quite a bit.

You can see this problem in action by going to the jsbin I linked above and slowly drag the slider to increase or decrease the rotation degree, especially when you drag the slider back and forth slowly.

That leads me to believe that this is not just a performance or framerate issue; it's most likely caused by the quick value changes that interrupt the transition.

**Please note** in the actual PhoneGap application, the compass value is refreshed every 200 milliseconds (or some other arbitrary interval) instead of the inconsistent update interval you see in the jsbin simulation.

I tried to play with the transition duration a bit and none of them worked. Here's what I've tried:

1. Tried to make the transition duration 0.5ms short than the value change interval. E.g. get new value every 500ms, set transition duration to be 450ms. Not only gives me stutter, but also make the entire transition lack significantly.
2. Tried to make the transition duration longer than the update interval (out of despair), surprised that it worked... For a little while then start giving me stutter again.
3. Tried to make the transition duration the same as the update interval, same stutters.

**Now my question is: How should I go about making the CSS3 transition smooth without stutter when the rotation value changes frequently?** Also, would switching to JavaScript animation alleviate this problem, like pausing the transition when the value changes?

**Solution:**

Replace CSS3 transition with Javascript animation. I used Velocity.js for the animation. Every time the compass heading value changes, I first finish the previous animation by doing `Velocity(compass_element, "finish")`, then I animate the `rotateZ` of that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw your post on CodeMentor. The issue is that every time the value changes, it *stops* the transition that is currently happening and starts another of the same (long) duration. If this is done in rapid succession, it doesn't look like it's doing much of anything because it is trying to ease in constantly and never gets very far into transition, causing the stutter.

You instead need to make the transition depend on the *distance to be traveled*, not just the *time* like you currently are. There are many ways to do this, a couple are as follows:

- Every time the value changes, calculate how far the pointer needs to move and create a transition for it based on some speed and easing inputs.
- Logarithmically approach the new target each time the value changes. This would mean that every nth of a second you would move towards the target something like 1/k of the way (so long as the distance is at least a pixel), where k is some constant like 2. So, if you transition the element half way every 0.05 seconds, it would near the target fairly quickly. The hard part about using this approach is getting an alright looking starting ease, I'm not sure how that'd work exactly, it'd likely require some playing around.

The other option (which I'd likely do personally) is just make the transition duration much shorter, something like 0.1s seems to work pretty well, when dragged. You could change the transition duration on dragstart to this shorter value and toggle it back on dragstop, leaving a longer transition duration for clicks.

Comment: Hey Zach, thanks a lot for taking the time to write a detailed explanation! Could you take a look at the "Please Note" section of my question? I added that part in yesterday... Sorry I didn't explicitly say it's an edit because not a lot of people noticed this question at the time. Thanks!

Comment: @user14412 My answer is in response to both parts :) If you have tried what I suggested then I'm afraid that I don't understand your problem adequately

Comment: Ya I will definitely try what you suggested today and let you know the results. Just thought I should tell you about my ninja edits in case you didn't see it.

Comment: sorry I really couldn't find time to try it during the last week, but I managed to try it today. First of all, thanks so much for your suggestions! I got rid of the CSS3 transitions and started using Javascript animation. The result is stunning! I'll post my findings in the original question.